# React Native Picker not showing all data

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

in my item Array i have 10 items.but when i view array in side React native Picker it only showing 1 item.
this is my picker

```
<Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.searchText}
                    onValueChange={(caseTypeList) => (this.setState({searchText:caseTypeList}))}  >
                    { this.state.caseTypeList.map((s, i) => {
                        return <Picker.Item
                                 key={i}
                                 value={s}
                                 label={s} />
                     }) }
                </Picker>
```

how can i solve this

Comment: This should work, see https://rnplay.org/apps/Syr1pA for a working example. Have you tried to add a console.log inside render() to check your state?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a flex style set on your picker? 
If so, take it out. That can mess things up on Android for some reason.